# How to create a field on an existing Ruby model without migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an existing model with >1,000,000 big objects in production. I need to add a new field to this model and migrating isn't an ideal option here. Is there a way I can add this field and slowly populate it overtime?

Ideally I'd have a model class like such

```
class Car
    
    field :name, type: String

end
```

and I could add a field and populate it each time it gets used?

```
class Car
    
    field :name, type: String
    field :year, type: String

    def year

        @year ||= '1997' 
    end
end
```

Any advice on if this is feasible or not? I imagine this is a common problem developers run into and I'm wondering the right way to go about this.

Comment: What is wrong with using a migration?  Can't see it slowing down your app or breaking anything.  Use a default on the field to initialise it.

Comment: why is migration "not ideal". It's perfectly benign. Why is the year field a string rather than an integer? With an integer you can easily select "newer than", "older than", "between" etc.

Comment: @LesNightingill This is just an example the data type is arbitrary:)

Comment: @BenTrewern it is not ideal because a migration would take a very long time. An ideal solution would be a lazy migration where we populate this models' field when we call it. Perhaps a default on the field is exactly what I need

Comment: Make a dump of your production database and test a migration out.  Unless you have a tiny server I doubt a migration to a table with >1,000 (<1,000,000) rows will take more than a fraction of a second.  I just tested adding a text field (with a default) to a table with 1,000,000 rows on Postgres and it took 15.493ms on a puny server I use.

Comment: Is this Mongoid? If so, you can simply define the `field` inside your model. Next time you save it, the field will be added to the corresponding document (not the entire collection, just that document). Maybe use a `before_save` hook to populate it prior to saving.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following @BenTrewern advice on using defaults.
So I made a private method and called it in the default.

```
class Car

    field :name, type: String
    field :year, type: String, default: -> { year }

    private

    def year

        '1997' 
    end
end
```

This didn't require a migration and was a simple change. I am wondering the implications of this if instead our default method relied on another field. How would I handle updating this field if the other one changed?

```
class Car

    field :name, type: String
    field :name_and_year, type: String, default: -> { name_and_year }

    private

    def name_and_year

        name + ' ' + '1997' 
    end
end
```

> In this example lets say Car['name'] = 'Toyota' Car['name_and_year']
> would be 'Toyota 1997' at default  but if we changed Car['name'] to
> 'Honda'  then Car['name_and_year'] would remain 'Toyota 1997' we could
> use after_touch but that would update it every time instead of only
> when the name field gets changed

Comment: You could use a `before_save` hook and set year only if `name_changed?`. Or override the `name=` setter and make it set year, too. BTW, none of these requirements (dependent on another field value, has to stay in sync) are part of your question. You should update it accordingly. And maybe not ask questions in an answer ;-)